# How to query ElasticSearch in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I'm hoping someone can help with the syntax for a simple query of ElasticSearch in a Laravel controller.

I have managed to index and output to a blade template in the view but I can't get the query right to enable the search form variable to perform a search on my seed data.

Search method from controller:

```
public function searchPlugins() {

    $client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

    $query2 = Request::input('query2');

    $params = [
        'index' => 'partnerpages',
        'type' => 'plugins',
        'body' => [
            'query' => $query2['query2']
        ]
    ];

    $plugins = $client->search($params);

    return View::make('search2')->with('plugins', $plugins);
}
```

I just can't get the query in the params array right - I could only get it to output for a specific field and keyword.

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT

Code to output in the view in my blade template:

```
<!-- Search engine -->
            <div class="col-md-8">

                {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'search-plugins2', 'class' => 'form')) }}

                {{ Form::input('search', 'query2', Input::get('query2', ''))}}
                {{ Form::submit('Search plugins') }}

                {{ Form:: close() }} 

            </div><!-- end of Search engine -->

            <div class="col-md-8">

                 <!-- insert Search engine -->
                <br/>
                <h1>Plugin results</h1>
                <br/>


                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body"><h2></h2>
                    <div><?php print_r($plugins);?></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div><small></small></div>
                </div>
                     </div>
            </div><!-- end of row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the query using the [query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html). You can start using the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'partnerpages',
    'type' => 'plugins',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'query_string' => [
                'query' => $query2['query2']
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks @Val, I'm getting the error "Illegal string offset 'query2'" which I understand to means I'm trying to access the value of an array using a key which doesn't exist i.e. query2. If I hard code the query then fine. I'll add the code from the view incase there's an issue there??

Comment: Just including the variable 'query' => $query2 worked - great! Thanks again Val. Still having problems outputting the array in a foreach loop though. Maybe because it's a multidimensional array, have resorted to print_r

Answer (score 0):

Just including the variable in the form of 'query' => $query2 worked for me. Thanks again Val for pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT

With updated code:

```
    public function searchPlugins() {

        $client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

        $query2 = Input::get('query2', 'RSS');

        $params = [
    'index' => 'partnerpages',
    'type' => 'plugins',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'query_string' => [
                'query' => $query2
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$plugins = $client->search($params);

        return View::make('search2')->with('plugins', $plugins);
    }
```

Comment: This is NOT an answer.  This should be a comment.  Please delete this, and make it a comment on the answer @val provided - OR, turn this in to a FULL answer, demonstrating the code that you used.